# Why are there only 3 episodes of "World War Blue"?

Tags: world-war-blue

So I thought that *World War Blue* was a pretty good idea for a show, but it only has 3 episodes.

Are there any explanations why it only got 3 episodes?

Comment: Short fact: the 1st episode was released on Oct 2012, 2nd on Dec 2012, and 3rd on Apr 2013. Speculation: it doesn't look like there was a plan for a 1-cour anime in the first place.

Comment: Well that sucks I actually kinda liked the idea